# Python sqlite3 with databases in different folders

Tags: python, sqlite

I have about forty SQLite3 databases that were created with Arduino and Python over almost three years; data from an experiment. I am using Python to summarize them. This software is mostly written. So, three folders: a raw data SQLite3 database, a summary SQLite3 database and then the Python code. (The present strategy has them in the same folder; default for Python.) I use the OS module but truthfully cannot seem to understand it. This code works:

```
bonn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\mrphy\\Desktop\\python sqlite march 2021\\033_mmsept__2020\\name_of_database')  
    
b = bonn.cursor()
```

I want to go from database to database with changes to the Python code to specify the next database.  The above could work. The double backslashes seem necessary. (I have two connection objects, of course. One for the source database and one for the summary database.)

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: I also don't see where there's an issue. If, as it sounds, the code to access each source database's information differs then you need to just write all that separately. Instead of, say, having one function to handle the 40 source databases and simply feeding the various database filenames to that function.